# Error "filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install `mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` on my windows machine.

The python version I am using is `Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. The system has a 64 bit word length.

When I run

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

I get the following error

> mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

What is the problem?

Comment: Where did you obtain the wheel? In spite of its name, it may not actually contain what's needed on your end. How do you establish what Python version you are using? Are you sure the environment the wheel is being installed into is actually the same environment you're getting the Python version for?

Comment: I found the wheel from [link]https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . The python version was found from the IDLE shell as it shows python 3.9 shell.

Comment: Try running `python --version` from the exact same command line you're running that `pip` command from, and make sure you're seeing the correct Python version there.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had two versions of python `python 3.8`  and `python 3.9` . When I run the command `py` on the command prompt, it shows the python version as `3.9` because when I installed python 3.9 it replaced the already existing environment variables.

But the pip command's environment variables were set up to run the script present in the installation folder of the python version 3.8. I edited the environment variable path to run the pip script present at the scripts folder of the python 3.9 installation and it solved the problem.